# How to determine whether the function has a left, right or no inverse?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

If the functions $f:A_{1}\to B_{1}$ and $g:A_{2}\to B_{2}$ are injective, then $h:A_{1}\times A_{2}\to B_{1}\times B_{2}$, where $h(x,y) = (f(x), g(y))$, has a left, right or no inverse?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I have edited your question (hopefully I have expressed it correctly). Please let us know what you have tried so that we can better help you.

Comment: So..... *Is* there $h_l^{-1}:B_1\times B_2\to A_1\times A_2$ so that $h_l^{-1}(h(x,y)) = h_l^{-1}(f(x),g(y)) = (x,y)$?  And is there  $h_r^{-1}:B_1\times B_2\to A_1\times A_2$ so that $h(h_r^{-1}(x,y)) = h(h_r^{-1}_{|_x}(x,y), h_r^{-1}_{|_y}(x,y)) =( f((h_r^{-1}_{|_x}(x,y), g(h_r^{-1}_{|_y}(x,y)))$?

Comment: I was thinking that since f and g are injective, then h is also injective, therefore it has a left inverse.